# Page break and table head on each page when printing. Print Table css issues

Tags: javascript, html, css

I am printing a table and can't figure out a couple of issues:

1. Page break on a table row to stop it printing half on 2 pages
2. Print the thead section on every page at the top.

Heres a link to the demo:

https://jsfiddle.net/DTcHh/18144/

Heres the code:

```
@media print {

   /* doesn't work */
    thead {display: table-header-group !important;}
    tr {page-break-inside: avoid !important;}
}
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Add the below CSS property in our CSS and try it for point 2

```
table {
        -fs-table-paginate: paginate;
      }
```

Change the CSS property like this to avoid break.

```
  tbody tr {
      page-break-inside: avoid;
   }

  thead tr {
      page-break-inside: avoid;
   }
```

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me, hope it helps:

```
table tr {
        -webkit-column-break-inside: avoid !important;
        page-break-inside: avoid !important;
        break-inside: avoid !important;
        display: table; /* this did it*/
    }
```