# How to add page break in browser print when printing a table data containing more than 1 pages

Tags: javascript, html, css

I search out many forums also followed css found in following article but it doesn't work

https://davidwalsh.name/css-page-breaks

[Page break and table head on each page when printing. Print Table css issues](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35936515/page-break-and-table-head-on-each-page-when-printing-print-table-css-issues?rq=1)

When I print page containing table data more than 1 pages it cuts last row of first page and first row of next page and so on.

Answer (score 0):

I have seen your referred links, in that they have applied 
"page-break-inside: avoid;" to tr,td and th. 
Try to apply this attribute to table itself not to tr,th and td.